# Do future electrical works invalidate a satisfactory EICR?

Tags: electrical, uk

I recently got a domestic EICR done for rental purposes. Certificate shows Satisfactory Result.

I am about to commission the fitting of a new light which will require wiring into the fuse board. Would this change to the property invalidate the certificate I currently have?

What should a qualified electrician provide for individual jobs to avoid having to do a full EICR retest every time some work is done?

(United Kingdom)

Answer (score 1):

The EICR is a report of the electrical installation at a particular point in time (like a vehicle MOT test certificate). It is not invalidated by any subsequent work.

Any electrical work done should be accompanied by a Minor Works Certificate (MWC) for small jobs, and this Certificate will be limited to the work done and will not test the rest of the installation.

It is a requirement of the IET Wiring Regulations that work is tested and certificated, and a requirement of NICEIC membership to follow the IET Regulations and issue certificates accordingly.

For rental purposes you would need an invoice to claim the cost of the work against tax, and a MWC to demonstrate compliance with your landlord's duty of care in respect of electrical safety.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I didn't know about MWCs. I've had various electricians do *minor works* over about a 10 year period and none have ever offered a certificate.

Answer (score 0):

From the reading I have done, a registered electrician should be able to provide a amended report since it was just completed, if a new report is necessary because you are having an electrician do the work.

Comment: Thanks. Electrician came, did work, and said no amendment was necessary to the EICR. Neither did he give me a cert for the work he did. I have no idea if that was correct or not.

Comment: Did you have a contract or receive a bill for the service work he did (the fixture install) from the reading I did that should be enough as long as he is “registered “ on this side of the pond that would mean licensed and bonded for the work.

Comment: He is registered with NICEIC but I have no contract or invoice. I hired him via a website so that probably constitutes evidence of engagement if it was needed. I'm not worried about this small job particularly, it was more of a general question about how to handle post-certificate changes.